# Naming Question. CNF Clauses vs DNF What?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

A Conjunctive Normal Form is a set of (conjunction of) clauses (disjunctions). A Disjunctive Normal Form is a set of (disjunction of) ? (conjunctions). I don't want to use the word conjunct because it is long and awkward and typo-prone. I have seen some people using the word "term". Any suggestions?

Comment: Term is fine, and is the standard use as far as I can tell. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Disregarding your question entirely: What you write their doesn't define a conjunctive normal form (you might be thinking of a sequence of formulae, rather than a set?).

Comment: If you say it is standard, I will use it. Because I have seen term to mostly mean "sum", while conjunction is a product. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Clement: "term" is standard for something else in first order logic. See my comment on Fabio's answer. "disjunct" (**not** "conjunct") is the standard term for an operand of a disjunction. So given that few people will understand "dual clause", "disjunct of a DNF" is my preferred suggestion.

Comment: @RobArthan I guess it's field-specific -- in learning theory/theoretical computer science, an AND of literals is referred to as a "term" (see e.g. [this](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Teaching/S12/Scribe/lec1.pdf)).

Comment: @Stefan: not a definition. Just trying to ask a short/understandable question and it is quite amazing how helpful people here are. I will use the terminology first in some algorithms I'm designing (we're comparing non-monotonic logic/higher complexity classes in the polynomial hierarchy algorithms to quantum algorithms, I'm also interested in VHDL synthesis, etc.) Actually, DNF is not very useful there because human designs (VLSI chips, etc) are almost in CNF but I sometimes use it to verify small-(ish) instances...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is no agreed terminology...

See [Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)):

> In logic, a *clause* is an expression formed from a finite collection of literals (variables or their negations) that is true either whenever at least one of the literals that form it is true (a *disjunctive clause*, the most common use of the term), or when all of the literals that form it are true (a *conjunctive clause*, a less common use of the term).

For a different proposal, see :

- Alan Robinson & Andrei Voronkov (editors), [Handbook of automated reasoning. Volume 1](https://books.google.it/books?id=X3z8ujBRgmEC&pg=PA23) (2001), page 23:

> A finite multiset of formulas may either be interpreted as the disjunction or as the conjunction of its elements.
>
> We will interpret multisets as disjunctions and speak of (general) *clauses*.
>
> On rare occasions we will interpret multisets as conjunctions, in which case we will speak of *dual* clauses.

Comment: "Clause" is very commonly used to denote disjunctions of literals.  There is no corresponding term with comparable circulation for a *conjunction* of literals.  I have nothing against "Dual clause," but it hasn't caught on.  A word that is sometimes used is "cube" .  It is short and descriptive (think subspace of a hypercube) but, unlike clause, I wouldn't use it without first defining it.  "Term" works well: it's just a bit generic.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: But "term" is commonly reserved for something else in first-order logic. In the CNF $(1 = 2 \lor 3 \neq 1 + 2) \land (x = 1)$, the terms (for me) are $1$, $2$, $3$, $1 + 2$ and $x$.

Comment: @RobArthan  True. In first-order logic "term" would be a bad choice.